# Unable to import google.cloud.kms_v1 in a Co-lab notebook

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import the `google.cloud.kms_v1` library in a Co-Lab notebook.

However, when I run the command `from google.cloud import kms_v1`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'kms_v1'
```

I was able to successfully import other APIs from the `google.cloud` library, such as `storage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed the library?

Prior to import, run:

```
pip install --upgrade "google-cloud-kms"
```